# recorrer la lista de argumentos condicionales, excluyendo el ultimo elemento ? python

Tags: python-3.x

Cuando paso un argumento por la terminal el modulo sys internamente los va agregando a una lista, entonces como recorrer esta lista de argumentos excluyendo el ultimo argumento. Teniendo eso en cuenta tengo una variable repe que hace referencia a el numero de veces que repite los otros argumentos(exceptuando el ultimo que es "iterar"), con un bucle for recorro el numero de veces que el usuario ingresa en la terminal, y con el segundo for anidado recorro la lista de argvs agregando slicing, los argumento anteriores a "Iterar" que se pasan también cumplen condiciones realizando diferentes tareas la idea es crear otra condicion if para repetir múltiples veces esas condiciones. la pregunta es Como recorrer la lista de argvs repitiendo argumento por argumento exceptuando el ultimo iterar(que es el que los repite)?

```
import sys

    if sys.argv[1] == iterar: # No importa el numero de argumento este siempre sera el ultimo
       repe = int(sys.argv[1+1])
       for r in range(repe):
           for a in sys.argv[0:-1]: 
               pass
```

se me ocurrió la idea de crear un script aparte con argparse. Este script tiene una función llamada bucle que recibe como argumento el método de la clase donde se encuentras las condiciones.

bucle.py

```
import argparse

def reproducir(funcion):
        analizador = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        analizador.add_argument('-i', type=int, help='Número de veces que repite la funcion')  
        numero = analizador.parse_args()

        if numero.i:
            for n in range(numero.i):
                funcion
```

Algo des este estilo.

Herramienta.py

```
import pyautogui
import os
import bucle

class Automatizar:
      def auto(self):
          ..............
          ..............
          ...........


V = Automatizar()
reproducir(V.auto())
```

esta seria una posible solución implementando el modulo argparse.

(Lastima no poder poner todo el código entero ya que es demasiado extenso el foro no me deja)

Comment: ¿No te has planteado usar [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) en vez del básico sys.argv?

Comment: no tenia informacion acerca de ese modulo, sin embargo queda en duda como recorrer esos comandos y repetirlos un numeros de veces

Comment: ¿La idea es iterar sobre los valores del resto de argumentos el valor paasado a -iterar verdad? Si agregas los otros argumentos y su tipo (entero, cadena, float, etc, ) esperado puedo darte un ejemplo con argparse.

Comment: la idea es iterar cada comando y realizar sus funciones un N de veces

Comment: Y creando un modulo externo que repita el script, donde se encuentran alojadas las condiciones.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) en vez de `sys.args`, aunque basado en éste, facilita mucho las cosas a la hora de parsear los argumentos, así como con la ayuda, validación, permite definir subparsers, etc.

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ejemplo de argparse.')

parser.add_argument(
    '-iterar', dest='N', action='store', required=True, type=int, 
    help='Número de veces que se aplicarán el resto de argumentos'
    )
parser.add_argument(
    "-foo",  dest="foo",  action="store", type=str, 
    help="Dummy foo arg"
    )
parser.add_argument(
    "-bar", dest="bar",  action="store", type=float, 
    help="Dummy bar arg"
    )

args = parser.parse_args()
N = args.N  # Valor del argumento -iterar

dict_args = vars(args)
del dict_args["N"]

for arg_name,  arg_value in dict_args.items():
    for _ in range(N):
        if arg_value is not None:
            # Aquí haces lo que quieras dependiendo del argumento
            print(arg_name,  arg_value)
```

### Ejemplos de ejecución

> ```
> $ python tests.py
> usage: tests.py [-h] -iterar N [-foo FOO] [-bar BAR]
> tests.py: error: the following arguments are required: -iterar
> ```

---

> ```
> $ python tests.py --help
> usage: tests.py [-h] -iterar N [-foo FOO] [-bar BAR]
>
> Ejemplo de argparse.
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>   -iterar N   Número de veces que se aplicarán el resto de argumentos
>   -foo FOO    Dummy foo arg
>   -bar BAR    Dummy bar arg
> ```

---

> ```
> $ python test.py -iterar 4
> ```

---

> ```
> $ python test.py -iterar 4 -foo "Hola"
> foo Hola
> foo Hola
> foo Hola
> foo Hola
> ```

---

> ```
> $ python test.py -iterar 4 -foo "Hola" -bar 13
> foo Hola
> foo Hola
> foo Hola
> foo Hola
> bar 13.0
> bar 13.0
> bar 13.0
> bar 13.0
> ```

El orden de los argumentos (dado que no se define ninguno posicional) es irrelevante, `-iterar` puede pasarse el último el primero o en mitad de los otros, siempre que se pase, dado que lo hemos definido como requerido. También podría ser opcional y darle un valor por defecto de 1 por ejemplo.

Si cada argumento lleva aparejado la ejecución de muchas lineas de código y tienes muchos argumentos, puedes englobar el código a ejecutar por cada argumento en una función/módulo/clase o lo que sea  y usar un diccionario para asociar el nombre del argumento con el callable de turno:

```
import argparse


############### Funciones con el código asociado a cada argumento #############
def foo_func(val):
    print("foo", ">>", val)

def bar_func(val):
    print("bar", ">>", val)

########### Diccionario para asociar cada argumento con su función ###########
FUNC_MAPS = {
    "foo": foo_func, 
    "bar": bar_func
}

##############################################################################


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ejemplo de argparse.')

parser.add_argument(
    '-iterar', dest='N', action='store', required=True, type=int, 
    help='Número de veces que se aplicarán el resto de argumentos'
    )
parser.add_argument(
    "-foo",  dest="foo",  action="store", type=str, 
    help="Dummy foo arg"
    )
parser.add_argument(
    "-bar", dest="bar",  action="store", type=float, 
    help="Dummy bar arg"
    )

args = parser.parse_args()
N = args.N  # Valor del argumento -iterar

dict_args = vars(args)
del dict_args["N"]

for arg_name,  arg_value in dict_args.items():
    for _ in range(N):
        if arg_value is not None:
            FUNC_MAPS.get(arg_name)(arg_value)
```

Comment: el modulo esta perfecto gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo estoy usando el modulo pyautogui y estoy viendo que hay que hacer las funciones separadas y luego añadirlas y me consumiria mucho codigo por que son como 20 condiciones, no abra una forma de crear un modulo para repetir el script x veces pero tambien tendria que pasar el N de veces por los argvs

Comment: @epalaarepa mira la edición de mi respuesta a ver si va por el camino que buscas.